# Verifying properties of given conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let's look at $\phi:\ z\mapsto -i\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ and try to verify in an elementary way that it maps the unit disk onto the upper half-plane:

My problem is the following: I can easily get $\phi^{-1}:\ z\mapsto\frac{i-z}{i+z}$. However, this doesn't mean $\phi$ is bijective, right? Getting an inverse function only works if the domain and the range are the same set?

So I will approach this a little more carefully: It is easy to verify by the definition that $\phi$ is injective. Now, to show that $\phi$ is also surjective on the given sets I need to show that for each $w\in\mathbb H^+$ (upper half-plane) a proper preimage $z\in \mathbb E$ can be found. So let's take some $w\in\mathbb H^+$, then the preimage I get by using the inverse function is $\frac{i-w}{i+w}$. And now we need to obtain $$\left|\frac{i-w}{i+w}\right|<1$$ using only $\text{Im}(w)>0$.

> Question 1: How do I do that?
>
> Question 2: Do I need ANYTHING else to obtain the upper statement or does completing question 1 include everything?

Comment: just square it and use $|z|^2=z\bar z$

Comment: I assume you mean $z=(i-w)/(i+w)$. I tried squaring that to show that the sign of $1-z\bar z = \dots $ depends only in $\text{Im}(w)$. Didn't work out though, so I'm missing something.

Comment: Try again since the difference above is precisely $4\Im{w}$ over a positive number ($|i+w|^2$). Note that only terms like $-i(w-\bar w)$ survive in the numerator when you square and subtract

Comment: Isn't the easiest solution just to show that three points on the real line are mapped to the unit circle and show some point in the open upper half plane is mapped to some point in the open unit disk? This shouldn't take more than a minute or so

Comment: I explicitly stated that I want to do it in an elementary way.